# AWS Athena would like to join table once instead of 3 times

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

Could you please help to rewrite SQL on AWS Athena to use table with one join instead of 3 times
I need to get result:

```
with t1 as (
    select 1 id, 1 id1, 2 id2, 3 id3
    union all
    select 2 id, 4 id1, 2 id2, 4
    union all
    select 3 id, 4 id1, 4 id2, 1),
t2 as (
    select 1 id, 'Text1' txt
    union all
    select 2 id, 'Text2' txt
    union all
    select 3 id, 'Text3' txt)
select t1.*, 
  coalesce(t2.id,t3.id,t4.id) t2_id,
  coalesce(t2.txt,t3.txt,t4.txt) t2_txt
from t1
    left join t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id
    left join t2 t3 on t1.id2 = t3.id and t2.id is null
    left join t2 t4 on t1.id3 = t4.id and t2.id is null and t3.id is null
```

Required result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmwjY.png)

I have tried:

```
with t1 as (
    select 1 id, 1 id1, 2 id2, 3 id3
    union all
    select 2 id, 4 id1, 2 id2, 4
    union all
    select 3 id, 4 id1, 4 id2, 1),
t2 as (
    select 1 id, 'Text1' txt
    union all
    select 2 id, 'Text2' txt
    union all
    select 3 id, 'Text3' txt)
select t1.*, 
   t2.id  t2_id,
   t2.txt t2_txt
from t1
    left join t2 on 
      case 
        when t1.id1 = t2.id then t2.id -- First condition (1)
        when t1.id2 = t2.id then t2.id -- Should be skiped if 1 is true (2)
        when t1.id3 = t2.id then t2.id -- Should be skiped if 1 or 2 is true (3)
      end = t2.id
order by t1.id,t2.id
```

Could you please advise.
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add the required result to your question as editable text

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would be helpful in terms of performance but you can try using `or` in join condition then grouping by the ids (alternatively you can introduce surrogate unique id with `row_number`) and then using `max_by` to select item which is matched by "earliest" id:

```sql
-- sample data
with t1(id, id1, id2, id3) as (
    values (1, 1, 2, 3),
     (2, 4, 2, 4),
     (3, 4, 4, 1)),
t2 (id, txt) as (
    values (1, 'Text1'),
    (2, 'Text2'),
    (3, 'Text3'))

-- query
select id, id1, id2, id3,
       max_by(t2_id, id_matched) t2_id,
       max_by(t2_txt, id_matched) t2_txt
from(
    select t1.*,
      t2.id t2_id,
      t2.txt t2_txt,
      case t2.id
        when t1.id1 then 3
        when t1.id2 then 2
        when t1.id3 then 1
      end id_matched -- surrogate order based on "first" matched id
    from t1
        left join t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id
        or (t1.id2 = t2.id and t1.id1 != t2.id)
        or (t1.id3 = t2.id and t1.id1 != t2.id and t1.id2 != t2.id)
    where t2.id is not null
    )
group by id, id1, id2, id3;
```

Output:

| id | id1 | id2 | id3 | t2_id | t2_txt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 1 | Text1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | Text1 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 2 | Text2 |